# Cost difference between a variable and a hardcoded value returned from a function

Tags: openzeppelin, erc-1155

Consider this

```
string private _uri;

constructor(string memory uri_) {
    _setURI(uri_);
}

function _setURI(string memory newuri) internal virtual {
    _uri = newuri;
}

function uri(uint256) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return _uri;
}
```

versus this

```
function uri(uint256) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return 'https://yadiyadi.yada/xyz';
}
```

Will the second one by cheaper to deploy?
And if yes, is it enough to justify manually adjusting the OpenZeppelin ERC-1155 template?

Comment: You could measure easily using remix for example.

Comment: @Ismael I am new here, would you mind directing me somewhere where I can learn how to do that?

Comment: Remix is an online IDE at remix.ethereum.org. There you could paste your contract and execute transaction in a browser session. It has an output log where the details of each transaction are logged, gas used is one of them.